# Emacs Comint History: Search Rather Than Navigate One By One

Tags: emacs, comint-mode

I would like to, after switching to the buffer where I usually run commands, navigate the history by searching it, rather than navigate one-command-at-a-time at the end of the buffer (e.g. `C-p`).

Basically I would like to "Reverse I-search" the *command history* at the end of the buffer, rather than search the *buffer*.

Did anyone code a working solution? Note that I noticed there is a Command History buffer available, but here it is just a bunch of text and it is not grouped well enough I think to use.

Comment: I don't understand you question. What's wrong with `M-r`?

Comment: @Daimrod That's exactly the answer I'm looking for!

Comment: Ok, I've added the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in a terminal, you can use <kbd>M-r</kbd> to search backward. It works in `comint-mode`, but it also work elsewhere, like in <kbd>M-x</kbd> (<kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>M-r</kbd>`pattern`<kbd>RET</kbd>).

Comment: After entering the search term, how does one iterate the previous matching commands?

Comment: I figured that out by trial and error: C-r appeared to go further back for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles).

In *Icicle* mode, command `icicle-comint-search` is bound to C-c ` in shell buffers. It gives you the behavior you are looking for.  It is described [**here**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Other_Search_Commands#toc10).

It uses only stuff that is in the currently visible history as candidates, however.  If you want to access stuff from your history from previous sessions then use command `comint-input-ring`, bound to `C-c TAB`, instead.  (This is explained in the [same doc](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Other_Search_Commands#toc10).)